# usage and meaning of 'until' in a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

.>Today  of  course,  we  have  electric  clocks  that  keep  giving  the  right  time  until  they  are unplugged or  the electricity  goes  off.

In this sentence, I'm confused with the usage of "until" .
Does this sentence mean

> electric  clocks will keep  giving  the  right  time  when they  are unplugged or  the electricity  goes  off. [Or]
>
> electric clocks stop giving the right time when they are unplugged or the electricity goes off.

Answer (score 1):

The word until used as a conjunction in the sentence means "up to the time that".  If something happens until a particular time, it continues happening and stops at that time.

So electric clocks stop giving time when they are unplugged or power is off.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it certainly means the latter. In general, a phrase that starts with "until" (or its variant "till") represents a point at which a state will no longer exist. However, often the dividing line isn't very sharp. Here are a few examples from songs:

"I'm going to love you till the stars fall from the sky" ("Touch Me", by the Doors)

"I want to hold you till I die" ("Sometimes When We Touch", by Dan Hill)

"You just keep using me until you use me up" ("Use Me", by Bill Withers)

"And here we'll stay until it's time to go" ("Until It's Time For You To Go", by Buffy Sainte-Marie

Depending on the details of the starfall, death, exhaustion, or parting, the transition is not always abrupt.